# a second ASP.NET web app hangs after deployed as IIS 'nested' Application onto primary web site

Tags: asp.net, windows, visual-studio, azure, iis

My IIS nested application hangs when I browse from IIS -- browser's busy spinner just spins forever.

I added a 2nd VS ASP.NET web app project to my primary web site, as a IIS 'nested' application.

The 2nd web app project debugs from VS OK and opens browser to it.

Is it possible to break in with debugger to see if code is in a loop or something?

BACKGROUND:
IIS 6.5 on my Windows Server 2012 R2 Azure VM
VS is 15.3.4

IIS > Sites > my primary web site > TEST (this Application added to primary) > Advanced Settings:
[image]
App Pool = DefaultAppPool
Physical Path = path to TEST's VS project
Virtual Path = /TEST

IIS 6.5...  [image]

[image]

Test Settings...

Answer (score 0):

If you aren’t sure what issue is causing your website to spin forever, look at the live requests within IIS. From the IIS Management Console select Worker Processes.

[image]

Right click on your running application pool and select “View Current Requests”.

[image]

This will bring up a list of the currently running ASP.NET web requests as shown below.

[image]

I would suggest looking at the “Time Elapsed” to see if you have a lot of requests that are taking a very long time. You should also see if they are all stuck in the same module. This could be a clue that the issue is all related to ASP.NET Sessions or some other step within the ASP.NET request life cycle. You may also be able to identify a specific URL that is causing the problem.

Also in addition to that  , I would highly suggest using a logging framework like NLog, log4net or Serilog. You can then send them to a log management service to make it easier to search them across multiple servers. Application logs are good way to trace your application trace across server.

If your web request is returning a 500 Internal Server Error, you need to check your server-side logs for exceptions. As mentioned above about application logs in general, it is important to have good exception handling in place and properly logging all of your errors.

Also you could use some open source diagnostic tool like Glimpse to trace. Glimpse is a thriving and growing family of open source NuGet packages that provides detailed performance, debugging and diagnostic information for ASP.NET apps. It's trivial to install, lightweight, ultra-fast, and displays key performance metrics at the bottom of every page. It allows you to drill down into your app when you need to find out what's going on at the server. Glimpse provides so much valuable information we recommend you use it throughout your development cycle, including your Azure test environment. While Fiddler and the F-12 development tools provide a client side view, Glimpse provides a detailed view from the server. You can try using that too.

Hope it helps.